# Filter nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this object inside another object and I need to filter them to get object without offline status.

I need to filter by modulos with "available" state and to get this I tried with a map, but this caused an error that map is not a function. I tried with filter, but this does not give me the correct result. I also tried with Object.keys, but I don't get the result that I need to work.

How can I filter a nested object?

```
{
  demo: {
    modulos: {
     demo1: {
        state": "offline",
      },
      demo2: {
        state": "available",
      },
    }
  }

  official: {
    modulos: {
      official1: {
        state: "offline",
      },
      official2: {
        state: "available",
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Which object or property are you trying to get?

Comment: Please show us your attempt at this.  You said you tried using `map` and `filter`. 
 Can you show us?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const object = {
  demo: {
    modulos: {
      demo1: {
        state: "offline",
      },
      demo2: {
        state: "available",
      },
    }
  },
  official: {
    modulos: {
      official1: {
        state: "offline",
      },
      official2: {
        state: "available",
      },
    }
  }
};

const filteredObject = Object.keys(object).reduce((acc, outerProp) => {
  Object.keys(object[outerProp].modulos).forEach((innerProp) => {
    if (object[outerProp].modulos[innerProp].state !== 'offline') {
      acc[outerProp] = {
        modulos: {
          [innerProp]: object[outerProp].modulos[innerProp]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(filteredObject);
```